# Tagging lists within lists for removal

Tags: python, list, duplicates

First off, I'm doing this in python,
I've got a complex list that will consist of a varying number of lists, I've tagged each list with a number (occupying the third position of each entry), because I want to cull lists that contain this number beyond the first, essentially removing duplicates beyond the first, so I might get a list like this:

```
list = [[[-.3,.9,1],[.2,.1,4]],[[.11,.22,1],[.01,.5,2],[.55,.5,3]],[[.3,.3,3],[.6,.7,4],[.8,.7,5]]]
```

I've got a list of varying lists, and those varying lists contain varying lists 
Breaking down the list I want to look at the third value in each list -
`[[[1],[4]],[[1],[2],[3]],[[3],[4],[5]]]` and then cull every entry beyond the first to get something like this;

```
finalList = [[[-.3,.9,1],[.2,.1,4]],[[.01,.5,2],[.55,.5,3]],[[.8,.7,5]]
```

Comment: What do you have so far?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: In the future, you should consider wrapping your list with your tag in a tuple: working with objects of the form `(tag, <list>)` is a lot easier and nicer than having to look up the third index all the time.

Comment: What do you mean "the third value in each list"? Which list? The inner lists, the outer lists, or all the lists? We need more examples.

Comment: The Inner lists - in each list I'll have an example of:
a = [[[x,x,1],[y,y,2],[z,z,3]],[[a,a,2],[b,b,5]],[[c,c,1],[d,d,2],[e,e,6],[f,f,7]]]

So I want to cull to end up with this.
b = [[[x,x,1],[y,y,2],[z,z,3]],[[b,b,5]],[[e,e,6],[f,f,7]]]

I've tried doing two for loops, to snag the index and then compare it to the same list, I run into the problem of how to differentiate the index from itself.  I suppose I could compare its first two values and if its a match then press on, I'm worried it will still return false positives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a lazy solution (untested).  I'm assuming that your original list is a "list of lists of lists" as per your example:

```
finalList = []
found = []
for i in list:
    miniList = []
    for j in i:
        if not j[2] in found:
            miniList.append(j)
            found.append(j[2])
    finalList.append(miniList)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works perfectly, if not was very handy, and its far simpler than what I was currently working on.

Comment: @Kenny Glad I could help!  Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: @Kenny I just wanted to mention that it's generally polite to accept an answer that works for you.  It might make people happier (and thus more willing to help in the future :) ): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat

Comment: Sorry, new to stack, I wasn't aware of the procedure, thanks again!